# Multiple Login users and passwords Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I want to make a login for a certain user with a certain password for multiple users. I know that `String user = new String("User")` hold the user login name but I want to be able to add multiple names and passwords. I would also like to know if its possible to have only certain passwords work with certain users.

P.S. I'm also a beginner, please go easy on me.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String greeting = "Hello";
        String username;
        String password;
        String user = new String("User");
        String pass = new String("Password");


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("*** Welcome to the program ***\n");
        System.out.println(greeting);

        System.out.println("Please type your username :");
        username = br.readLine();   
        System.out.println("Please type your password :");
        password = br.readLine();


        if (username.equals(user))
            System.out.println("They are the same");
        else 
            System.out.println("That is wrong");

        System.exit(0);

        if (password.equals(pass))
            System.out.println("They are the same");
        else 
            System.out.println("That is wrong");
        System.exit(0);                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is for a homework assignment, use a map. Assuming this is for a real security system, use a database and encrypt the password.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to be able to use multiple users and passwords.

Comment: That's not a question. A question ends with a question mark. A good question would be: I want to blablabla, here's what I tried: ..., how should I blablabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a list of users that you can iterate through, looking for a match. Each user has a username and a password associated with it. We will create a new class called User, put in it's own file User.java:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    User (String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    String getUsername() {return username;}
    String getPassword() {return password;}
```

}

Now, going back to the code you had written, the following creates a list of those users, adds a few dummy users to it, and then iterates through that list looking for a match. This should get you on your way.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String greeting = "Hello";
        String username;
        String password;

        // Used to hold the instance of a user who successfully logged in
        User loggedInUser = null;

        // Create an empty list to hold users
        List<User> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add 3 users to the list
        listOfUsers.add(new User("user1","password1"));
        listOfUsers.add(new User("user2","password2"));
        listOfUsers.add(new User("user3","password3"));

        // Get user input
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("*** Welcome to the program ***\n");
        System.out.println(greeting);

        System.out.println("Please type your username :");
        username = br.readLine();   
        System.out.println("Please type your password :");
        password = br.readLine();

        // Iterate through list of users to see if we have a match
        for (User user : listOfUsers)
        {
            if (user.getUsername().equals(username))
            {
                if (user.getPassword().equals(password))
                {
                    loggedInUser = user;

                    // when a user is found, "break" stops iterating through the list
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // if loggedInUser was changed from null, it was successful
        if (loggedInUser != null)
        {
            System.out.println("User successfully logged in: "+loggedInUser.GetUsername());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, respect the basic Java conventions. Methods start with a lowercase letter. And fields are typically declared at the top of the class, not at the end. I'd upvote your answer if this was fixed.

Comment: Doh, I'll eventually shake the naming convention habit, not sure why I left those fields dangling down there :)

Answer (score 0):

As Compass said you can use a map.

```
    private static Map<String,String> passwdMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    static {
        passwdMap.put("kmick", "somepass123");
        passwdMap.put("gjames", "q8secret");
    }
    public boolean check(String user, String password){
        return password != null && user!=null && password.equals(passwdMap.get(user));
    }
```

Then a personal advice: *parenthesize defensively*, try to use

```
if(condition){
   action();
}
```

instead of

```
if(condition)
  action()
```

Because it' quite easy to make mistake updating code afterwards.

Comment: `passwd.equals(passwd.get(user));`: that's incorrect. You wouldn't have made the mistake if you chose a good name, like passwordMap, instead of passwd.

Comment: @JBNizet, oops, you are right, you always learn, especially when you try to tech...

Answer (score -2):

You can use two String array, one for the users names and the second for the users passwords. Instead of `if`, you can use `switch n case`.

Answer (score -2):

```
(!password.equals(PASSWORD) && !username.equals(USERNAME)) !=  (!password.equals(PASSWORD) || !username.equals(USERNAME) )
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.